# Tefillin - Are there any others who wear 4 x 4 battim besides Chabad?

Tags: minhag, tefilin, chabad, chasidut-hasidism

Lubavitch minhag calls for the tefillin battim to be 4 x 4 cm based on the Baal HaTanya's ruling in the [Shulchan Aruch HaRav, 32:63](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3284478/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-32-Laws-Relating-to-Writing-of-Tefillin.htm). Are there any other communities who have the minhag to use Chabad-sized battim or is this exclusive in Lubavitch?

Normal-sized battim are 3.5 x 3.5 cm or sometimes smaller, and I believe this is based on the Shulchan Aruch of Rabbi Yosef Karo, but I'm not sure.

Obviously, I don't expect there to be any non-Chasidic communities who use these "oversize" battim but surely there must be some Chasidic dynasties which use them as well.

I am specifically looking for a community's custom, not "there's a guy at my shul who wears Beis Yosef tefillin with Chabad battim" or anything like that.

Answer (score 5):

There is a large type of tefillin called shimusha rabba which sefardi kabbalists wear at mincha. You can read a good deal about them at http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/08/tefillin-shimusha-rabba-and-raavad/

In addition the shulchan aruch harav quotes שימושא רבא (shimusha rabba) as the source for having large tefillin [link](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3284478/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-32-Laws-Relating-to-Writing-of-Tefillin.htm#footnoteRef%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%93a3284478)

Comment: the Lubavitcher rebbe put 4 pairs of Tiflin rashi, rabenou tam, chimoucha rabba, rabad and the 4 had a size 4*4 it seems to me